# make a loop wait till previous pass has completed

Tags: javascript, loops

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function pageLoad(links,site)
{
var links = links.split(","); 
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    var link = links[i]
    $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Processing');
    setTimeout($.post( 
         "downloadlinks.php",
         { link: link, site: site, iter:i},
         function(data) {
            if(date == "ok")
            {
                $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Finished');
            }else
            {
                $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Failed');
            }
         }), 10000);
    }
 }
</script>
```

hello this is myy script I have made, but I don't want it to post every pass at the same time, i need it to wait till the previous pass has finished.

How can I do this?

Matt

Comment: If you're using jQuery please update your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive way like this instead of a loop..

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function pageLoad(links,site)
{
var links = links.split(","); 
var i=0;
postNow();
function postNow() { 
    var link = links[i]
    $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Processing');
    $.post( 
         "downloadlinks.php",
         { link: link, site: site, iter:i},
         function(data) {
            if(date == "ok")
            {
                $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Finished');
            }else
            {
                $('#info'+(i+1)).html('Failed');
            }
            i++;
            if (i<links.length){
                postNow();
            }
         });
    }
 }
</script>
```